# show mask on input library

Tags: javascript, jquery

I add mask to my input fields with [jQuery mask plugin](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin), but this is not enough.

Is there any library that can show mask while input.

Like if I input date don't just validate it to mask dd/MM/yyyy. But I want not just validate input but to show mask the whole time.

Example with the date

1. empty input `__/__/__`
2. first digit `1_/__/__`

and so on ..

Is there enything like this or i should write custom solution?

I don't need Date picker or anything like that, cause I need to use this for phone inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [InputMask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) plugin or simply use the HTML5 input type date, but this doesnt work on firefox or IE 11 and below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>
Depending on browser support:<br>
A date picker can pop-up when you enter the input field.
</p>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  Birthday:
  <input type="date" name="bday">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```